# nextauth jwt callback not being called using discord provider

Tags: api, next.js, oauth-2.0, discord, next-auth

i'm currently trying to use the `DiscordProvider` from `next-auth` to authorize with discord using the OAuth2 flow so I can query the discord API once succesfully logged in, however; it seems that the `jwt` callback is not being called, and i'm not sure why. For the record, it doesn't reach any console logs inside the `jwt` callback

This is my my code:

```
 import { type GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next";
import {
  getServerSession,
  type NextAuthOptions,
  type DefaultSession,
} from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { env } from "~/env.mjs";
import { prisma } from "~/server/db";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      console.log("i get here");
      console.log("account", account);
      console.log("token", token);
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        await console.log(token.accessToken);
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
        },
      };
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      token: "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
      userinfo: "https://discord.com/api/users/@me",
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope:
            "identify email guilds applications.commands.permissions.update",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```